# Merge images/ overlaying an image on another (regarding performance and quality)

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, uiimage

I thought of two different ways to palce an image on top of another (e.g. adding a watermark on an image), but I am not sure about which one of them is better regarding the performance and the quality of the final image.

**Method A:**

1. create an UIImageView base_img, set the base image as the image of the view
2. create an UIImageView watermark, set the watermark image as the image of the view
3. create an UIView, add base_img and watermark as its subview respectively
4. obtain the final image as an UIView

**Method B:**

1. use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to initialize a graphic context
2. draw the base img
3. draw the watermark
4. obtain the final image as UIImage

I guess method B will have better performance as it involves fewer objects creation, but I am not sure about that. And I don't know if there will be another differences regarding the final image. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if those images aren't huge you won't see that performance impact. The correct method is B if you want to obtain a UIImage object with both the contents, if you are trying just to overlap two images in the "device view" the first one is the way to go and probably the faster, because it will not require offscreen rendering.